# Как сделать MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT uniqe id рандомальный?

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать к примеру `ID 600000` при добавлении новой строчки?
Чтоб был рандом например `6000023` следущий `6000073` и так далее...

Comment: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,425424,425491

Comment: То есть не вообще рандом, а именно инкремент рандомный? а, стесняюсь спросить, за каким ... ?

Comment: @Akina Вероятно хочется реализовать велосипедное секционирование/шардирование на несколько серверов. Типа 60000 - это префикс сервера, а 23 и 73 - это рандомные значения.

Comment: мне надо чтоб id был не предсказуемым чтоб не знали что где лежит. как это сделать простым способом. @StereoFlo это не работает

Comment: ток вчера отвечал тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/905041/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-id/905524#905524 у вас тоже самое, но проще

Comment: так не проще ли отказаться от автоинкремента и использовать GUID как идентификатор, который можно генерировать на стороне php.

Comment: Мне нужно именно то что я спросил, если кто сталкивался как это оформить в mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать триггер after insert с обновлением вашего уникального поля (например, добавить некоторое число), а затем выполните ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = XXX;

Comment: $lastid = mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM contract");
   $lastidarr = mysql_fetch_array($lastid);
   //echo $lastidarr[0];
   $randContract = ($lastidarr[0] + rand(10,100));
   echo "rand contract: " . $randContract;
   mysql_query("ALTER TABLE contract AUTO_INCREMENT={$randContract}");